# Replace string using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I replace 'http://' or 'https://' from a text added with javascript?

I am also interested in regex solutions.

Here is what I made so far:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wLrjtjt3/3/)

HTML:

```
<div class="string"></div>
```

JS:

```
$text = $('.string').text("http://www.text.com");

if ($text.startsWith('http://')) {
    $text.replace('http://','');
}
else if ($text.startsWith('https://')) {
    $text.replace('https://','');
}
```

Comment: You need to assign back the replaced value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue stands in what $text contain. it contains the element, not the text!

try this code:

```
$text.html($text.html().replace('http',''));
```

**update**

editing and simplifying your code it would be:

```
$text = $('.string').text("http://www.text.com");

$text.text($text.text().replace('https://','').replace('http://',''));
```

**update (again)**

You can also use a regex to do it.

```
$text.text( $text.text().replace(/http(s?):\/\//g,'') );
```

Plaease check this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wLrjtjt3/7/).

Answer (score 1):

Check this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/wLrjtjt3/5/)

```
var $text = $('.string').text("http://www.text.com");

if ($text.text().indexOf('http://') != -1) 
{
    $text.text( $text.text().replace('http://','') );
}
else if ($text.text().indexOf('https://') != -1) {
    $text.text( $text.text().replace('https://','') );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var $text = $('.string').text("http://www.text.com");

$text.text($text.text().split('://')[1]);
```

This code will remove any protocol from your URL.