# How to replace textually "blahblah" by "sometext"?

Tags: jquery

How can I replace (with jQuery) a text (not element or attribute value) "blahblah" (without quotes) by a new text "sometext" (without quotes)?

Comment: Without any more detail or code, all we can do is point out that this has been answered many times here already, eg  https://stackoverflow.com/q/11324559/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/11867269/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/38052211/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/8146648/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/36010608/6089612, ... and many more. If you already did your research and have tried those and they don't help, then you need to edit your question and describe why not.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "blahblah";
str = str.replace("blahblah","sometext");
console.log(str);
```